# Are snapshot images identical on devices with different physical dimensions but with the same pixel dimensions and same dpi

Tags: android

In Android, if I have multiple devices from different manufacturers and each device comes in different physical sizes but all of them have the same number of pixels in width and height and all have the same dpi, will bitmaps (the Bitmap object) contain the exact same image if a screen shot is taken from all of them?

So if I have two devices that are 1440 x 2560 with a 300 dpi but one device is 100 mm 200 mm but the other device is 150 x 250 mm, will a snapshot stored to a png file be the same (assuming that you take a snapshot using the two-button click method)?

Or are there other properties about the devices that I haven't considered that could end up generating different images?

Comment: Well, different screen densities will have different font sizes, and other resources can be selectively loaded based on screen density, so... "it depends".

Comment: My question was about having the same densities, so font sizes are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

#### Not necessarily

Android rendering isn't guaranteed to be pixel-perfectly identical across devices.

The biggest differences are likely to occur across API version changes.  For instance, text rendering improved significantly in KitKat (for instance, it gained ligature support).  Almost any layout containing text would look different after that update.

More subtle differences in the 2D rendering could occur as the underlying libraries like Skia are updated.  Generally, I wouldn't count on exactly reproducible results unless they're coming from the same device.  It's *possible* that it will be the same, but there could be differences.